# Woocommerce на странице оформления заказа не отображается стоимость доставки

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

У меня проблема с woocommerce поскольку мне известно в дефолте woocommerce показывает способы доставки и цены доставки , в настройках у меня все вроде бы сделано правильно ,  цена доставки
до 20000 - 1000 драммов  после 20 тысяч доставка бесплатная, это все я настроил , попробовал хуки добавить  но тоже не помогло, может кто то еще сталкивался с такой проблемой ?
цену за доставку в total он считает, но клиент же должен знать за что с него берут 1000 драммов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]